# Stellar operations priority

Tags: horizon, operations

What order is used to execute operations in ledger? I mean those operations who passed fee filter

Sorted by

- time of submission
- fee
- random order?

I tried to find this information in docs, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Seems like random order?

> Transaction apply order is determined (Validator Network): Once SCP
> agrees on a particular transaction set, the apply order is computed
> for the transaction set. This both shuffles the order of the set to
> create uncertainty for competing transactions and maintains the order
> of sequence numbers for multiple transactions per account.

Source: https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/transactions/#transaction-lifecycle